# Raising events from within catch block

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, try-catch

I am trying to raise an event from a catch block, basically I have a class in which I do some processing and if it throws and exception I need to know this from the calling method. Because of the distributed nature of this solution exceptions are logged and thrown and handled in a different way therefore I have no way of bubbling the exception to the surface therefore no way of knowing that the process is failed from the calling method, I tried to raise the event from the finally block and also tried passing a boolean variable as ref and setting it to false in the catch but it also did not work. The following is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var error = false;

        var demo = new Demo();

        ProcessThis(demo, 0);

        demo.ErrorEvent += () => error = true;

        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ProcessThis(Demo demo, int val)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = 10/val;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");

            demo.RaiseErrorEvent();

            throw;
        }
    }

    public class Demo
   {
    public event ErrorDelegate ErrorEvent;

    public delegate void ErrorDelegate();

    public void RaiseErrorEvent()
    {
        if (this.ErrorEvent != null)
        {
            this.ErrorEvent();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're subscribing to the event *after* you've called `ProcessThis`...

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach the event handler before you call your method:

```
demo.ErrorEvent += () => error = true;
ProcessThis(demo, 0);
```

This will still not work since you are using `throw;`. You need to catch the exception in `Main` method.